# Refresh page after update $hasMany relation

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I have a form model with $hasMany relation manager in backend (display with `relation_render` method).

When i update the relation model, i update too a parent model attribute

```
public function afterUpdate() {
    // update related model
    $related_model = Related_model::find($this->related_model_id);
    $related_model->searchable = !$this->suspensive;
    $related_model->save();
}
```

Then i have to refresh the form model page after saving relation to prevent to ovveride modification if user click save.

No idea how to do this. thanks for help

*subsidiary question: let me know if there a better workflow to accomplish this task*

Comment: Did you try : https://octobercms.com/forum/post/form-aftersave-refresh

Comment: can you tell us current workflow using some images and more more description , what you try to achieve then we can suggest some cool resolutions :)